# I think the datasnapshot value is returning null because when I run it the TextView is empty, eventhough there is a name in the database firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

the code below is for a tictactoe game however that works my problem is where I want to show the players name in this activity and the input of their names is from another activity which the code for that is in PlayerNames.java.

Games.java code:

```
package com.example.tictactoe2;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.Objects;

public class Game extends AppCompatActivity {

FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://playernames-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/");
DatabaseReference dbRef = database.getReference();

Button [] buttons = new Button[9];

int p1Score, p2Score, playerStatus;
int p1ScoreCount, p2ScoreCount, rountCount;
boolean activePlayer;
int [] gameState = {2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2};

int [][] winPositions = {
        {0,1,2}, {3,4,5}, {6,7,8},
        {0,3,6}, {1,4,7}, {2,5,8},
        {0,4,8}, {2,4,6}
};



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);

    TextView p1n = findViewById(R.id.p1);
    TextView p2n = findViewById(R.id.p2);

    Query pp = dbRef.child("Players");


    pp.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot nsnap: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    String p1 = (String) nsnap.child("1").getValue();
                    String p2 = (String) nsnap.child("2").getValue();

                    p1n.setText(p1);
                    p2n.setText(p2);
                }
            Toast.makeText(Game.this, "it worked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(Game.this, databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });


    XoGame();


}
```

the code below is for the activity where the user inputs their names in an EditText as shown below for the first player it's p1Name and the second is p2Name. their names are stored in the database by setting the value. the names are getting stored in the database correctly I've checked. the problem is when it's retrieved from the database in Game.java.

PlayerNames.java code:

```
package com.example.tictactoe2;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class PlayerNames extends AppCompatActivity {

FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://playernames-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/");
DatabaseReference dbRef = database.getReference();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_player_names);

    EditText p1Name = findViewById(R.id.player1);
    EditText p2Name = findViewById(R.id.player2);

    Button cont = findViewById(R.id.contbtn);



    cont.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String n1 = p1Name.getText().toString();
            String n2 = p2Name.getText().toString();


            dbRef.child("Players").push();
            dbRef.child("Players").child("1").setValue(n1);
            dbRef.child("Players").child("2").setValue(n2);


            Intent i = new Intent(PlayerNames.this, Game.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

}
}
```

I think the problem is in the for loop for DataSnapshot or maybe where I converted the snapshot to String. it's not showing the names of the players even though it's in the database in firebase I checked. it's showing null.

firebase realtime database:
[image]
activity where player names are input from user:
[image]
TextView where it should output:
[image]
the output is null after pressing continue:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the key while pushing values as it'll be considered a node in the tree, and then set your `String` values

```
String key = dbRef.child("Players").push().getKey();
dbRef.child("Players").child(key).child("1").setValue(n1);
dbRef.child("Players").child(key).child("2").setValue(n2);
```

And retrieve them with:

```
Query pp = dbRef.child("Players").child(key);
pp.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
...
```

Comment: I'm getting an error for the key that it isn't a string so I think it should be converted to string maybe but I don't know how. Thank you for helping!

Comment: @shadan my bad .. just modified the answer with `.getKey()` after pushing a reference. please have a look

Answer (score 0):

add below code outside your `oncreate method`.

```
public interface myCallback{
    void onCallback(String p1,String p2);
}

public void getData(final myCallback myCallback){
    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Players");
    reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            String p1 = (String) snapshot.child("1").getValue();
            String p2 = (String) snapshot.child("2").getValue();
            myCallback.onCallback(p1,p2);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
}
```

Then add below code inside `oncreate method` after `TextView p2n = findViewById(R.id.p2);`

```
getData(new myCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onCallback(String p1, String p2) {
            p1n.setText(p1);
            p2n.setText(p2);
            XoGame();
        }
    });
```

And remove `TextView p2n = findViewById(R.id.p2);` to `}`.
Hope this will work.

Comment: it's still not showing. can you check the images I added to my question so you can see what's wrong. Thank you so much for helping!

Comment: I have edited my 2nd code. Check if it works or not.